# How to using code from other project appsciprt?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

My situation is like this: My friend has written code for his Google Forms, and I want to use this code for my Google Form. What should I do? Of course, not just copy and paste, because I need to manage and share it with many other users as well.